# IsPointerOverGameObject. I couldn't calibrate it properly

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, user-interface, game-development, touch-event

I made the game not start when I pressed the UI icons on the game start screen. However, this time the game does not start when I press another area other than the UI icons. I tried the solutions I found on the web. It took me 2 days. Unfortunately I did not get any results. Am I skipping something? help please.

```
private bool speedBallForward = false;
private bool firstTouchControl = false;

public void Start()
{
    rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

public void Update()

{
    if (Variables.firstTouch == 1 && speedBallForward == false)
    {
        transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        cameraFollow.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        vectorBack.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        vectorUp.transform.position += new Vector3(0, 0, forwardSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
    }

    if (Input.touchCount > 0) 
    {
        touch = Input.GetTouch(0);

        if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Began)
        {
            if (!EventSystem.current.IsPointerOverGameObject(Input.GetTouch(0).fingerId))
            {
                if (firstTouchControl == false)
                {
                    Variables.firstTouch = 1;
                    UIManager.DeactiveAfterGameStart();
                    firstTouchControl = true;
                }
            }
        }

        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved)
        {
            rb.velocity = new Vector3(touch.deltaPosition.x * speedModifier * Time.deltaTime,
                transform.position.y,
                touch.deltaPosition.y * speedModifier * Time.deltaTime);
        }

        else if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Ended)
        {
            rb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
        }
    }
}
```